# Unity Parent's SetActive() influences child?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I discovered that when setting a parent true, that parent's children are all called 'OnEnable' function. Even though children are all set true already.

I don't want to call 'OnEnable' function even though it's already set true.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

SetActive() behavior is inherited by all of the children of that particular gameObject. In order to solve your problem you most likely have to restructure your GameObject hierarchy.

Comment: hmm... if they're all from MonoBehaviour, it it possible to restructure?

Comment: By restructure I mean to take a step back and think does your objects A, B, C... have to inherit object Y in case that you want to set Y's active to false and A, B, C... to true ? Why does your other objects have to depend on object Y ? If you share some code/screenshot we can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation on execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) may be useful  to you.

If you have logic in the child objects that you do not want to call from the parent being set as active, than remove it from `OnEnable` and hook it up to your own delegate somewhere else.

You are going to have the same thing happen with the `Start` and `Awake` functions as well. Personally I would try and find a way to abstract your code a bit more to make sure the child object is not dependent on the parent.